Multiple unlocked packages with different namespace possible in one salesforce org?
Hello Salesforce Ohana,
I am looking for suggestions/help if someone has implemented Unlocked packages with multiple namespace in single org as we have 3-4 applications in salesforce and we are trying to decouple it so that there is restriction on not using classes and components from different project

how to communicate between multiple namespace packages

Is it possible to create one namespace package and one without namespace package where we can add all the metadata like objects,labels,reusable apex classes,etc

What are the challenges and points to keep in mind to implement it?

is it really useful to implement?

I couldn't find much resources on unlocked packages especially for Namespaces unlocked packages. If you have any good content for reference could you please share


Thanks in advance.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.


how to communicate between multiple namespace packages

Mark the methods/classes as global.

Is it possible to create one namespace package and one without namespace package where we can add all the metadata like objects,labels,reusable apex classes,etc

As I recall, this is possible, just make sure you declare your dependencies appropriately.

What are the challenges and points to keep in mind to implement it?

The main limitation to be aware of is you can only have 10 namespaces in one transaction. And, of course, you'll have to deal with global/public accessors on your code, as appropriate. It may also cause complications when installing/upgrading/uninstalling packages. Nothing insurmountable, just keep in mind that more complicated setups are more complicated.

is it really useful to implement?

It can be in certain scenarios. Particularly when you have independent teams building features/apps and you want to avoid accidental code conflicts.

I couldn't find much resources on unlocked packages especially for Namespaces unlocked packages. If you have any good content for reference could you please share

Namespaces are more of an ISV feature, so you'll learn quite a bit in the ISVForce Guide.

Hi sfdcfox,
Thank you for your quick help on the above queries I had.
I created two classes as global
ExternalClass(Part of namespace package)
ControllerInOrg(Exist in org but not part of any org)
when I am trying to install package I am getting below error
ExternalClass: Variable does not exist: ControllerInOrg
Any Idea if i am missing any step here?
global class ExternalClass {
global static Contact getContact() {
return ControllerInOrg.getContact();
}
}

Hi @sfdcfox,
code global class ControllerInOrg {
global static Contact getContact() {
return [Select Id,Name From Contact LIMIT 1];
}
}
